# iphone facebook login safari cannot open the page

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am trying to integrate facebook sdk 3.1.1, I am getting issue in authenticating , when I authorize the app in safari it says "Cannot open page" - "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid" 
any guesses ?

**EDIT :** if there is account added in settings it works fine, but if the there is no account linked, then have to open the session i open like this

```
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
```

it opens the safari after authenticating the app[Okay], safari popups for "Cannot open page" and doen not open the app. Other ways of authenticating ???

Comment: did you add your Facebook app id in `.plist`?

Comment: @Ankur see the edit, yes app id is inserted, but when i share it say from iOS and doesnot show the app. any clues

Comment: can you tell me the fb app id you are using so that I can check it with my app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dint know or found any documentation that there is also facebook appid under
Project > Target > Info > URL Types > URL Schemes besides plist

in my case it was not there but in sample projects from facebook it was there, I inserted the appid with fb and it worked perfectly

**Edit**: put fb in front of your app id eg. fb123456789

Comment: clarification for readers: put fb in front of your app id eg. fd123456789.

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example from the latest Facebook "Hackbook" sample code.
Open you Info.plist file.
Construct the URL Types / URL Schemes as follow:

[image]

The large number next to fb... in Item 0 of URL Schemes must be you Facebook app id as found on you Facebook app dashboard.

Answer (score 3):

Suporting Files -> info.plist Right click Open As -> Source Code.

Make sure you have

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb0123456789</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>012345678</string>
```

where 0123456789 is your Facebook app key

Answer (score 0):

Found the anwser in my case
I had deleted the "URL types" entry in the info.plist file
Follow the facebook tutorial:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/ Bullet 5

Once I added URL types with URL Schemes with fb again it worked
Hope it helps 
BR
@wazzaword

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue on Simulator, on device it works fine (when all settings are correct ofc)