# Launching facebook event URL results in 'Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid'

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari

If I open the following URL (I had to add a screenshot as Stack Overflow does not allow shortened links in question bodies):

[image]

in Safari on an iOS device then Safari does succeed in opening the Facebook event page but it then overlays an error dialog on top of it saying 'Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid'.

This can be seen in the following screenshot:

[image: Simulator screenshot of issue]

I believe the issue is related to the fact that I do not have the Facebook app installed on my phone and the link being launched is a 'universal link'.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to stop Safari showing this error dialog for the link if the Facebook app is not installed on the device?

I have looked at dozens of threads and articles about this issue and the majority just suggest clearing Safari's data, which does not solve the issue for me.

I am seeing this issue when an iOS app that I am developing opens URLs submitted by users. Some answers, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14460368/6630965) suggest adding the Facebook app id to the info.plist file under URL Schemes. However, this does not seem very future proof to me. As the issue will reoccur if the app tries to open a similar link but from Instagram or Snapchat etc etc.